# Game Progress Lost after Restoring from Backup?

Tags: fallout-shelter

So there was a problem with my iOS device, and I restored it to a backup created a few weeks ago to be safe. However upon loading Fallout Shelter all the progress since the backup had been lost (quests, expansions, stats) Is my current game data still in the cloud - and if so, can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the instructions of Bethesda.

> 1. Launch Fallout Shelter on your Android or iOS device.
> 2. Navigate to the Vault List from the main menu.
> 3. Select the Cloud checkbox that corresponds to the save slot the vault was originally saved from.  If a vault save file exists, you
>      will receive a message prompt
>      stating that there is a save conflict.
> 4. You will then be able to restore the vault save file to your device by selecting the appropriate cloud save file. The save file will then
>      download to your device and be ready to play
>
> Please note that it is not possible to transfer your Vaults between
>   different platforms (Andoid, iOS, PC) in Fallout Shelter. Cloud saving
>   is not available on PC at this time.

You can check the original page from bethesta.

http://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/31236

Comment: To avoid link rot, add an outline of the instructions that this link provides. That way, should the site ever go down, users will still he able to see the instructions required for this. You can then use the link as a source.

Comment: No worries! It's just a precaution, and a good practice to get into :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, David. However, I already had the Cloud option checked on the vault and it still reset to the progress made until the backup - that's why I was so confused.